# Split strong to separate fields - Velocity code Marketo Java

Tags: java, velocity, marketo

I have some working code:

```
#if( !$lead.First_5_Lines_in_Basket__c.isEmpty() )
#set( $First_5_Lines_in_Basket__c = $lead.First_5_Lines_in_Basket__c )
#foreach( $fivelines in $First_5_Lines_in_Basket__c.split("\n", -1) )
${fivelines.replaceAll("Part","<br><br>Part")}
#end
#end
```

Which outputs puts the following:

Part - 7984219, P2220 Oscilloscope Probe, Passive, 300 V Qty. - 11

Is it possible to split the First_5_Lines_in_Basket__c field to 3 separate field, such as

```
Field 1 = Part - 7984219
Field 2 = P2220 Oscilloscope Probe, Passive, 300 V
Field 3 = Qty. - 11***
```

This will allow me to place field anywhere within an HTML table.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You actually already have most of your answer in your code—in this case, because you're using `$fivelines.replaceall`, there's no reason you couldn't use this with a little regex to split your string into individual lines, then add those each to an array that you'd output as a table. The real difficulty comes with `$fivelines` itself, as it's not marked up in a way that makes it straightforward to split out your field values. If you can alter that somehow (whether that's adding a separator character, structuring the data in some way, etc.) that will go farther and make whatever solution you come up with less fragile.

Comment: Thanks Courtney! Will you be able to help update the code(I am at a blank mind here) - the comma probably best to use in this scenario?

Comment: Sorry this is the output with comma as separator: Part - 7984219, P2220 Oscilloscope Probe, Passive, 300 V Qty. - 11